# jsf auto-login according to cookie

Tags: jsf, cookies, authentication, redirectwithcookies

I'm having a problem in achieving an auto-login feature for my JSF application which is being proted from a JSP & servlet-based architecture.

I used LoginBean backing the jsf page with a constructor method to check if the cookie containing the user crendtials exists, and if it does to automatically open a session and redirect the user to the main page.

The auto-login never takes place and the user always remains in front of the login form. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: when you say "auto-login never takes place" do you mean that the Constructor is not being called?

Comment: the constructor is called however, the navigation to the "loggedin" page does not take place without still submitting the form. What I'm trying to achieve is that the user is redirected automatically to the "logged in" page if the cookie is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option that should work. You can do something like this once you've ascertained that they are valid:

```
final ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

try {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    if (!response.isCommitted()) {
        externalContext.redirect("loggedin.xhtml");
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // log etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Dave. Where exactly should I put this snippet of code? Inside the managed bean or a servlet filter whatsoever?

Comment: you could put it in the Constructor of your Bean right after you've decided they have a valid cookie.

Comment: Thanks Dave. It seems to work, I have a question though: what's the difference between performing redirect under condition of response.isCommitted() and not checking if the response is committed at all?

Comment: You get an exception if you try to redirect after the response is already committed. You can just deal with this scenario in the catch block if that would represent an error in the context of your application.